# Scale Y-Achsis in plotly candlestick chart

Tags: r, charts, scale, plotly

I am searching for a way to (auto-)scale the y-axis of a candlestick chart. If you take a look at the following example (from https://plot.ly/r/candlestick-charts/)

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL",src='yahoo')

df <- data.frame(Date=index(AAPL),coredata(AAPL))
df <- tail(df, 365)

p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
          high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~AAPL.Open, line = list(color = 'black', width = 0.75)) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

The y-axis has autoscal="normal", so it takes min and max from the dataset, but if you zoom, these values stay the same. It would be clearer for me to have the min and max of the current (zoomed/viewed) part of the graph
[image: not zoomend]

[image: zoomed in]

Until now i could not find a way to implement this feature, does anyone know a way to do so?

Amother solution for me would be just to get the "normal" zoom from charts like in this example:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat,
        size = ~carat, text = ~paste("Clarity: ", clarity))
```

Comment: Doesn't work with slider as far as I know, https://community.plot.ly/t/can-you-rescale-y-axis-to-fit-data-when-zooming-in-x/2918

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to remove slider, so that i can get the second solution, but with candlesticks?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the slider within the candlestick chart is not autoscaling the y-axis for me either. Plotly team may not have solved it yet for candlesticks charts. autorange = TRUE is working neither.

But if anyone is using this in a shiny application, the workaround which can work is to have a date slider reactively connected to Plotly graph. The steps are as following:

1. create a date slider with a start and end selected

**ui.R**

```
...
uiOutput("dateSlider")
...
```

**server.R**

```
  output$dateSlider <- renderUI({
     sliderInput(
      "dtSlider",
      "Select a date range:",
      min = min_date,  
      max = max_date,
      value = c(max_date - 30, max_date),  # in this case last 30 defines start and end
      timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d",
      width = '80%'
    )
  output$dateSlider <- renderUI({
```

2. In the RenderPlotly section of server.R calculate a data.frame  with data filtered from start to end using `input$dtSlider[1]` and `input$dtSlider[2]` correspondingly and then use the new reactively filtered data.frame in the Plotly code.

**ui.R**

```
plotlyOutput("candleChart")
```

**server.R**

```
output$candleChart <- renderPlotly({
...
df <- as.data.frame(dbFetch(res)) # querying DB to pull data with new input$dtSlider[1] as start and input$dtSlider[2] as end
...
fig <- df %>% plot_ly(x = ~timestamp, type="candlestick",
                          open = ~open, close = ~close,
                          high = ~high, low = ~low )

...

})
```

So now if we change the date slider, y-axis range changes automatically as shown below from same data.frame object:
[image]
[image]